# Assigining primary key column value to foreign key column

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables called `VisitorMaster` and `SupportVisitor`.
In `VisitorMaster` I have a column called `VisitorID1` which is a primary key (but not an identity column).
In `SupportVisitor` I have a column called `VisitorID2` which acts as a foreign key for the `VisitorMaser` table.But my requirement is I want the last generated column value of `VisitorID1` to be inserted in `VisitorID2` of `SupportVisitor` table.
How to achieve this..
Please Help??

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking your best bet would be to ensure that you wrap your `INSERT` into the `VisitorMaster` table with a transaction and that within the transaction you obtain the value of `VisitorID` using the data you've inserted to query it and finally putting that into `SupportVisitor` before either committing or rolling back the lot.

You could use a trigger to do this but triggers are nasty things that can have all kinds of unintended consequences since the operate more or less invisibly so I'd steer clear of them.

Ultimately though I'd ask why have you got a non-identity surrogate PK in one column? It's a pretty bad bit of design. Either use a natural key (combination of forename, surname, timestamp or whatever makes a natural unique key) or use an auto-incrementing identity field as a surrogate PK (whereupon you then **can** use `SCOPE_IDENTITY`) because otherwise your key is pretty shaky and not guaranteed to be unique. How are you generating this value? Is it held in a separate table (I've known some databases use this kind of system, especially EAV model databases, and it is not a good system in any way shape or form and isn't much easier to deal with than arbitrary values)? If you have any influence over this design at all then you should change it because this smells and is likely to cause you many, MANY more problems in future.

Comment: thanks Steve.Actually I have created a store procedure called 'USPGETMAXID' and executed that up on 'VisitorMaster' table to increment the 'VisitorID1' column value by 1 for each time user enter something to the table.so should i make the coulumn 'VisitorID1' an 'Identity Column' or i can achieve this through my procedure..please help me out?

Comment: Unless you have some really pressing need to avoid it, then I would definitely make the column an identity column. This means you don't need to have the SP and therefore don't have to maintain it. Both natural and surrogate keys have their places but they should each be used when most appropriate and going on what we know from your question, I'd say an identity field is what you're after here for minimum hassle and maximum usability.

Answer (score 0):

After inserting a record into a table with an IDENTITY-column you can retrieve this rows numeric identity by selecting  the scope identity:

```
INSERT INTO VisitorMaster (Name) VALUES ('Jane doe')

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() -- Will retrieve ID for Jane Doe
```

Comment: -1 This will not work: The OP specifically stated that `VisitorID1` is NOT an identity column and therefore SCOPE_IDENTITY will not return the value of it, nor will the `INSERT` increment it in any way. This answer is pointless and does not relate to the question.

Comment: Thanks Elken..My column 'VisitorID1' is not an identity column..is there any way out for this..or i am bound to make it an identity column.